# web server access from browser. not from xcode

Tags: php, ios, json, localhost, mamp

I am struggling with something strange. I am trying to get back a json value from internet to my iOS app. Everything works fine when I catch something from the internet (like ip.jsontest.com). I can get my JSON array.

Things get more complicated from my local webserver (MAMP on my Mac). I have a very simple php script returning a json value. A kind of:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array("key1"=>"value1"));
```

I can see it displayed in my browser, at the address: http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8888/script.php. It works perfectly, the json array is displayed.

But when I type in **the exact same address** in my objective-C code for the URL with NSURLSession, it seems that it cannot reach the webserver (I get the error 3480, Cocoa operation not completed, as if there was no json returned).

I was wondering if anybody knew those kinds of problem between a working website and an apaprent not-working-webserver running locally.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

I mentioned http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8888/script.php but it is also not working with
    http://localhost:8888/script.php

Comment: did u try by placing that script in test folder in your mama application and the url should be something like : http://localhost/script.php ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I placed the file in the htdocs of my xamp.

```
"http://localhost/sample.php"
```

Comment: Thanks foy your replies but my file is in the htdocs folder. I can also run it with localhost:8888/script.php in my browser but again it is not working from my obj-C code. Any ideas why?